# Does X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE7" work in IE10 and IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer

i am currently working with this header:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

1) so...is the following assumption correct?

the metatag attribute content="IE=EmulateIE7" ensures that no matter with what IE-version you look at the page the page will be rendered as if you look at it in IE7. E.g. you won't see rounded corners defined with border-radius when you look at the page in IE10 or IE9.

2) is this following assumption also correct?

however, as of IE11 the http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" metatag will be obsolete so the same page will be rendered with the IE11 rendering engine and there will be rounded corners.

Comment: It's being deprecated, it will however still work. So if you have http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" in your page IE11 will still render it as IE 7. Have a look at this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ok so no matter if IE9, IE10 or IE11 i will see the website rendered with the IE7 engine?! :)

Comment: Should do, or as close to it as it can.

Comment: @Jerryf cool..so if you post your answer below i will give you the green tick ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just adding this here to that the question can be marked as answered...

It's being deprecated, it will however still work. So if you have http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" in your page IE11 will still render it as IE 7. Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So if Microsoft decides to drop EmulateIE7 in a future release of IE, sites that still use it by then may become graphically messed up for IE-users with the latest browser. Thanks for the warning. Not too sure if this will positively influence the image of IE though, as it is bound to affect a lot of sites owned by people and companies that were unaware of such an upcoming change.

Comment: @alphapecap Not necessarily. If Microsoft decides to stop supporting (legacy) document modes then any latest version of IE will simply render pages using standards mode. If a site has been built to include support for browsers (other than IE) that support modern standards in any case, then I doubt that it would have a significant impact (apart from minor tweaks and fine tuning of course). Unless we're talking about a large-scale site/app that targets IE exclusively using only legacy document modes. It really depends on the implementation.